# How to synchronize my local PostgreSQL with my heroku database for my website built using Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I have created a website using Django as backend and recently hosted it with heroku. Also, I have uploaded my local database on heroku, now I have added some more rows in my local database and want to synchronize my local database with my heroku database so that whenever I add some items in my
local database, it is also added to the heroku database.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Generally speaking, this isn't a good idea. Data is a form of state, and state should be allowed to vary between different instances of your application. Why do you want to do this? There's a good chance that you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your use case, which you haven't provided any information about. Generally speaking, your local deployment *should not* share state with your production deployment.

It's possible you have a unique situation, but lacking any details on what it might be, it seems like some of your data needs to exist in all deployments, whether or not they're production. This is a good case for [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/initial-data/) and/or [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

I think it's also worth noting that, while data migrations might address your requirements, you might also be doing something that's better handled in a [model field with `choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#choices). It's a way to keep data in code as constants when it needs to be carefully controlled and only changed with a release update.